# What is the name of the philosophy that believes one should do whatever they want?

Tags: terminology, metaethics, definitions, hedonism

The philosophy in question believes:

- You only live once, and you have predetermined desires from your genetics and environment. If these desires are not fulfilled as short-term or long-term goals you will live a miserable life.
- So you should act on those desires, no matter how anti-social, despicable or illegal they are. (If you like helping people, help them, if you like hurting people, hurt them) to live a happy life.

What is the name of this amoral hedonistic philosophy?

Comment: There is no such philosophy because it is incoherent. Anti-social, despicable or illegal are not the problem, the problem is that many desires conflict with laws of nature and with each other. One may want to shoot heroin and live long and prosper too. We can't even always tell what is and is not possible now or how acting on a desire now will affect the possibilities later. Doing whatever you want just ain't gonna happen.

Comment: The root of our desires is unknown and subjective according to mainstream philosophy so hence why it is one of the 'beliefs' that provides a theoretical explanation just like all of the other philosophies, I'm not trying to prove it right or or wrong, I'm asking what the belief is called. The belief definitely exists or otherwise there would be no selfishness in the world, and its not like we can 'change' our desires, eg. Homosexuals do not choose to be gay. The heroin desire was covered in the fact that the environment also triggers our desire for instantaneous pleasure.

Comment: There are hedonism, egoism, immoralism, but all of them move past the "I wanna" philosophy and deal with complicated issues like physical limitations, clash of desires, their articulation, and obscurity of finding ways to act on them, each in their own way. It is unclear from your description which way you prefer. The rudimentary "belief" described does not survive a minute's consideration, so selfishness and realization of desires need better outlets than that. It is not about right and wrong, it is about thinking it through.

Comment: Might be [_hedonistic egoism_](https://iep.utm.edu/hedonism/#SH1e). Notice the priority of the self in front of others, which is what you seem to ask for.

Comment: Instead of discounting the philosophy as an "I wanna" philosophy (seems like strawman to me) and then saying that the philosophies concerned are more complex topics (basically sums up what you said), explain why it is invalid instead of saying it 'does not survive a minute's consideration', explain why because its survived more than a minute for me.

Comment: I take it you would reject YOLO as an answer? How about Rand's Rational Egoism? ; )

Comment: Try it and see what happens. Experimental Philosophy! Full-contact sport!

Comment: Sounds like Eric Cartman's philosophy, "Whatever, I do what I want!"

Comment: @RodolfoAP That is interesting. I think this might be the closest answer, if not the answer, of my question, it considers short term and long term consequences (hence mentioning "net-pleasure"), but what would differentiate a hedonistic egoist from a psychopath/sociopath? Nothing?

Comment: @ScottRowe And now I want to see it on existentialcomics one day.

Comment: @AshtonDowling: good question, probably the difference is that an hedonist has a positive drive: improving his own conditions, no matter the rest, while a psychopath has a negative drive: harming others, no matter his own self (since they show no remorse and can even enjoy being imprisoned, I assume they would feature moreover traits of stoicism, not hedonism).

Comment: Are you talking about Moral Nihilism or perhaps Ethical Egoism?

Comment: Well if you don't masturbate Males you may put yourself at a higher risk for prostate cancer. Also if we don't fulfill sexual needs it's possible to become neurotic. Freud. He was right btw. Comment intended as food for thought.

Answer (score 8):

[Here](http://www.justethics.com/Articles/ArtMID/2952/ArticleID/8/Hedonic-Nihilism) is a blog post proposing a concept of "hedonic nihilism", which comes very close to what is described in the question.

> Hedonic Nihilism is an amalgamation of two philosophical ideas.
> [Hedonism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hedonism/) can be seen as a school of thought which suggests that the
> pursuit of pleasure is the primary, if not only, intrinsic good in
> human life. Now pleasure may not mean purely that of sensation (food,
> sex, drugs etc), but for the purpose of Hedonic Nihilism I will focus
> purely on these. The hedonist seeks to maximise net pleasure (pleasure -  pain) as they believe this is the ultimate good, the sumum bonum. [Nihilism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihilism) is the philosophical view that there is no intrinsic meaning
> to any aspect of life.
>
> Existential Nihilism suggests life has no intrinsic value and from
> this we get Moral Nihilism, which states that morality is not
> something that is inherent to objective reality. Now you’re probably
> putting the pieces together and understanding what Hedonic Nihilism
> means. To put it simply: Hedonic Nihilism is the belief that because
> there is no inherent value in living a good life, the only way I
> should live is to maximise my own sensational pleasure.

As it says explicitly, "Hedonic Nihilism" is just something this blogger made up. However, hedonism is very much a coherent philosophical tradition tracing back to the ancient Greeks. Nihilism is more of a general grouping of modern continental philosophical currents.

Comment: No... This belief of hedonistic nihilism is different because its implying that one should just become obese and smoke party drugs until they die at 30. That is not the belief in question because it does state "long term goals" as well. Would you consider an entrepreneur working for 5 years to reach a desired profit margin "instant gratification", or gratification in general? Is this long-term gratification still considered "pleasure" like hedonistic pleasure? Normally hedonism isn't associated with long-term sacrifices and successes.

Comment: @AshtonDowling "Normally hedonism isn't associated with long-term sacrifices and successes." It can be, though the author above explicitly chooses not to consider this. It may be of interest to look at how [the Cyrenaics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrenaics) discuss altruism, family, etc.

Comment: @AshtonDowling If your idea can include working really hard at something for quite a while to get what you want, then it seems... Normal.

Comment: I don't totally agree - I don't see anything in that definition saying that it only cares about the short-term? I hadn't heard the term, but I love it - certainly how I try to live my life, the maximization of overall lifetime happiness. (That is: if you died at 30 from all the drugs you took, you are NOT maximizing overall happiness, as you lost all the happiness you would have had the rest of your life! Etc. That also provides an internally consistent reason not to hurt people, steal, etc, even if you didn't care about others' happiness: because it's hard to enjoy life from jail. :p)

Comment: The equation (happiness - pain) would probably produce a bell shaped curve: trying too hard for happiness will increase pain and offset it. In other words, maybe the Buddha had something with his "middle way" notion?

Comment: @ScottRowe You can never try too hard in my opinion, that subjective 'too' adverb is added by others to invalidate a course of action, in this case its used to put people down for their ambition (equivalent of calling them "tryhards"), as long as the effort aligns with logic it can only provide rewards (return on investment) in the short or long term.

Comment: @AshtonDowling. You can try too hard if you keep trying despite evidence that trying is futile. Many people continue to strive towards goals they are unlikely (never going) to achieve. Take the boxer who persists in sustaining brain damage, deluded by unrealistic ambition. The effort may seem 'logical', in that they have been persuaded that their efforts are worthwhile by unscrupulous agents, but in reality it serves only to damage/destroy them.

Comment: I think 'do people with mental illness/brain damage have valid philosophies' is a different discussion entirely. For example, a high-functioning psychopath may preach the philosophy in question, but nobody is going to listen to what he has to say because the label 'psychopath' automatically invalidates his opinions because people assume he is crazy.

Answer (score 5):

> [Thelema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thelema) is is a Western esoteric and occult social or spiritual **philosophy** and new religious movement founded in the early 1900s by Aleister Crowley (1875–1947), an English writer, mystic, occultist, and ceremonial magician. The word thelema is the English transliteration of the Koine Greek noun θέλημα (pronounced [θelima]), "will", from the verb θέλω (thélō): "to will, wish, want or purpose."

> The only rule of this Abbey was "fay çe que vouldras" ("Fais ce que tu veux", or, "**Do what thou wilt**")

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this, as is, would fall into any singular philosophical idea.

The problem is that avoiding anti-social, despicable or illegal behaviour may, in itself, be included in your desires.

> You only live once, and you have predetermined desires from your genetics and environment. If these desires are not fulfilled as short-term or long-term goals you will live a miserable life.

I would probably agree with the [Brian](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/95784/6350) that pursuing these desires for their own sake is [hedonism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedonism).

It's also somewhat related to the idea that [free will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will) doesn't exist, which is not to say you'll be miserable if you act against those desires, nor that you "should" act in line with them, but rather that it's *literally impossible* for you to act against those desires.

But one may desire to avoid anti-social, despicable or illegal behaviour under either of these concepts.

> You should act on those desires, no matter how anti-social, despicable or illegal they are

This sounds somewhat like [anarchism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism). But anarchism is about actively pushing against authorities and hierarchies to bring about social change, whereas what you mention sounds closer to indifference to them. I'm not aware of a term for this.

It's quite closely related to [ethical egoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethical_egoism), which is "the normative position that moral agents ought to act in their own self-interest". Helping others wouldn't typically be included here, but one might argue that the motivation behind helping others in this case is egotistical rather than [altruistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altruism_(ethics)). But still, one might follow social or legal rules, as doing so is often in one's own self-interest. An egoist would, however, not avoid illegal behaviour just because it's illegal, but rather they'd judge it based whether they'd suffer negative effects.

Comment: Well... The criteria states 'no matter' it doesnt imply 'you must (do antisocial stuff)' which gives complete freedom to the self as it doesnt bias towards either acting ethically or unethically, rather it allows all possibilities. I even clarified that if the self liked helping others (out of intrinsic kindness, not to leverage something else) the philosophy would allow the self to do that

Answer (score 2):

It reminds me of the position of the character *Callicles* in Plato's dialogue: *Gorgias*. It also reminds me of Nietzsche's concept of *will to power*.

Maybe this [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/callicles-thrasymachus/#Call) entry will be useful:

> Callicles’ version of the immoralist challenge turns out to involve
> four main components, which I will discuss in order: [1] a critique of
> conventional justice [nomos], [2] a positive account of ‘justice
> according to nature’ [phusis], [3] a theory of the virtues, and [4] a
> hedonistic conception of the good.

[2] and [3] seem to match your first point, and both [1] and [4] with your second point.

> [1] Callicles locates the origins of the convention in a conspiracy of the
> weak: “the people who institute our laws are the weak and the many…
> they assign praise and blame with themselves and their own advantage
> in mind” (483b). This diagnosis of ordinary moral language as a mask
> for self-interest is reminiscent of Thrasymachus; but there is also a
> contrast, for Thrasymachus presented the laws as adapted to serve the
> strong, i.e., the rulers. Callicles is perhaps more narrowly focussed
> on democratic societies, which he depicts as involving the tyranny of
> the weak many over exceptional individuals. The many “mold the best
> and the most powerful among us … and with charms and incantations we
> subdue them into slavery, telling them that one is supposed to get no
> more than his fair share” (483e–484a). This rhetorically powerful
> critique of justice inaugurates a durable philosophical tradition:
> Nietzsche, Foucault, and their successors in various projects of
> genealogy and ‘unmasking’ are all Callicles’ heirs.

> [2] For all its ranting sound, Callicles has a straightforward and
> logically valid argument here: (1) observation of nature can disclose
> the content of ‘natural justice’; (2) nature is to be observed in the
> realms where moral conventions have no hold, viz among states and
> among animals; (3) such observation discloses the domination and
> exploitation of the weak by the strong; (4) therefore, it is natural
> justice for the strong to rule over and have more than the weak.

> [3] Callicles’ theory of the virtues: As with Thrasymachus, Socrates’
> response is to press Callicles regarding the deeper commitments on
> which his views depend. He first prods Callicles to articulate the
> conception of the ‘superior’ which his account of natural justice
> involves. Callicles has said that nature reveals that it is just for
> the ‘superior’, ‘better’ or ‘stronger’ to have more: but who are they
> (488b–c)? In practice, as Socrates points out, ‘the many’, whom
> Callicles has condemned as weak, are in fact stronger: they are able,
> as Callicles himself has complained, to suppress the gifted few. So,
> like Thrasymachus when faced with the fact that rulers sometimes make
> mistakes in the pursuit of self-interest, Callicles now has to
> distinguish the ‘strength’ he admires from actual political power.
> (This leaves it unclear whether and why we should still see the
> invasions of Darius and Xerxes as examples of the ‘strong’ exercising
> the ‘justice of nature’; since both their expeditions were notorious
> failures, the examples are rather perplexing anyway.)
>
> Callicles goes on to articulate (with some help from Socrates) a
> conception of ‘superiority’ in terms of a pair of very traditional
> sounding virtues: intelligence [phronêsis], particularly about the
> affairs of the city, and courage [andreia], which makes men “competent
> to accomplish whatever they have in mind, without slackening off
> because of softness of spirit” (491a–b). These are the familiar
> ‘functional’ virtues of the Homeric warrior, and the claim that such a
> man should be rewarded with a ‘greater share’ is no sophistic novelty
> but a restatement of the Homeric warrior ethic: the best fighter in
> the battle of the day deserves the best cut of the meat at night. At
> the same time, Callicles is interestingly reluctant to describe his
> ‘superior’ man as possessing the virtue of justice [dikaiosunê], which
> we might have expected him to redefine as conformity to the justice of
> nature. Instead, he seems to dispense with any conception of justice
> as a virtue; and he explicitly rejects the fourth traditional virtue
> which Plato will take as canonical in the Republic, sôphrosunê,
> temperance or moderation.

> [4] It is not made clear to us what pleasures Callicles himself had in
> mind—perhaps he himself is hazy on that point. All he says is that the
> superior man must “allow his own appetites to get as large as possible
> and not restrain them. And when they are as large as possible, he
> ought to be competent to devote himself to them by virtue of his
> courage and intelligence, and to fill him with whatever he may have an
> appetite for at the time” (491e–492a). This seems to leave the content
> of those appetites entirely a matter of subjective preference. And
> Callicles eventually allows himself, without much resistance, to be
> committed by Socrates to a simple and extreme form of hedonism: all
> pleasures are good and pleasure is the good (495a–e). Their arguments
> over this thesis stand at the start of a fascinating and complex Greek
> debate over the nature and value of pleasure, which is here understood
> as the ‘filling’ or ‘replenishment’ of some painful lack (e.g., the
> pleasure of drinking is a replenishment in relation to the pain of
> thirst). However, it is difficult to be sure how much this discussion
> tells us about Callicles, since it is Socrates who elaborates the
> conception of pleasure as replenishment on which it depends. Even the
> strength of Callicles’ commitment to the hedonistic equation of
> pleasure and the good is uncertain. At 499b, having been refuted by
> Socrates, he casually allows that some pleasures are better than
> others; and as noted above, hedonism was introduced in the first place
> not as a thesis he was keen to propound, but as the answer to a
> question he could not avoid—viz, the stronger should ‘have more’ of
> what? Callicles’ philosophical enthusiasm is not, it seems, for
> pleasure itself but for the intensity, self-assertion and extravagance
> that accompany its pursuit on a grand scale: he endorses hedonism so
> as to repudiate the restraints of temperance, rather than the other
> way around. One way to understand this rather oddly structured
> position is, again, as inspired by the Homeric tradition. Callicles’
> somewhat murky ideal, the superior man, is imagined as having the
> arrogant grandeur of the larger-than-life Homeric heroes; but what
> this new breed of hero is supposed to fight for and be rewarded by
> remains cloudy to his imagination.

Comment: links tend to die; best to copy in the part or parts you feel are relevant

Answer (score 2):

Given the clarifications given in the comments, what you describe is not much of a philosophy as a lack thereof, a.k.a. "normal human existence".

As Conifold has said, what you describe would be incoherent as a philosophy, because a philosophy attempts to establish some kind of a system. It is defined by the general statements it makes, such as "if you steal, karma will eventually catch up and bust your punk ass" or "burning churches is universally fun". You have not established any beyond the standard hedonistic framework, really. And one may not explain their actions by this one principle alone, heavily leaning onto *ad hoc* arguments.

If you declare that no more general statements could be produced at all, and it is *ad hoc* all the way down, that is nihilistic and thusly arrives at [Brian Z's answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/95784/58306). If no such declaration is made, then it is simply hedonism (and indeed, hedonism does not imply the absence of long-term goals).

Answer (score 1):

How about Thomism?

https://www.newadvent.org/summa/2001.htm#article7

> On the contrary, Augustine says (De Trin. xiii, 3) that all men agree in desiring the last end, which is happiness.

Technically, everyone is seeking the same last end: happiness.  So, everyone is doing what they want.  Everyone differs in what they think will make them happy.

Seems identical to what you say here:

> So you should act on those desires, no matter how anti-social, despicable or illegal they are. (If you like helping people, help them, if you like hurting people, hurt them) to live a happy life.